# How to merge some spannable objects?

Tags: android, spannable, charsequence

I divide a spannable object into 3 parts, do different operations, and then I need to merge them.

```
Spannable str = editText.getText();
Spannable selectionSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, selectionStart, selectionEnd);
Spannable endOfModifiedSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, selectionEnd, editText.getText().length());
Spannable beginningOfModifiedSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, 0, selectionStart);
```

How can I do it? I haven't found the required method or constructor to do it.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You could use this:

```
TextUtils.concat(span1, span2);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat(java.lang.CharSequence...)

Comment: Sometimes, not very often, Java makes things easy.  I love those times.  +1

Comment: @Madbreaks this is not related to Java, but to Android API. It could be made easy in C++ as well.

Comment: In my case this method had some problems: `TextUtils.concat(span1, " ", span2);` style (ie span) for span1 disappeared, only it's string representation left. Wrapping " " into Spanned didn't help.

Comment: Same thing here first spannable loses styling only the second one maintains its style!

Comment: If your first span style disappeared, it could be because you've used the same `StyleSpan` on both spans. You need to create a new `StyleSpan` for each span. (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5999171/1440076))

Comment: @marwinXXII the `" "` is a `String`, which works with the `CharSequence` interface however it is not a `Spannable`. `new SpannableString(" ")` would work in place of `" "`

Comment: @marwinXXII I've found a workaround for this in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080221/5054192

Answer (score 23):

Thanks, it works. I have noticed that I can merge even 3 spannable object:

```
(Spanned) TextUtils.concat(foo, bar, baz)
```

Comment: If you look at the method signature, it takes CharSequence... which means it will merge as many as you give it.

Comment: Works just fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old. But after modifying kotlin stdlib a bit I've got this code:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.joinToSpannedString(separator: CharSequence = ", ", prefix: CharSequence = "", postfix: CharSequence = "", limit: Int = -1, truncated: CharSequence = "...", transform: ((T) -> CharSequence)? = null): SpannedString {
    return joinTo(SpannableStringBuilder(), separator, prefix, postfix, limit, truncated, transform)
            .let { SpannedString(it) }
}
```

Hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 8):

Use `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Even better- make a kotlin operator overload:

```
operator fun Spannable.plus(other: Spannable): Spannable{
    return SpannableStringBuilder(this).append(other)
}
```

just throw that in any kotlin file as a top level function.

and the you can concatenate using `+`:

```
val spanA = ...
val spanB = ...

val concatenatedSpan = spanA + spanB
```

Answer (score 2):

As marwinXXII said in a comment, using `TextUtils.concat` does work but can cause loss of styles in some cases when you have multiple instances of the same span in a single `CharSequence`.

A workaround could be to write the `CharSequence` to a `Parcel` and then read it back. Example Kotlin extension code to do this below:

```
fun CharSequence.cloneWithSpans(): CharSequence {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    TextUtils.writeToParcel(this, parcel, 0)
    parcel.setDataPosition(0)
    val out = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)
    parcel.recycle()
    return out
}
```

Example usage of this code:

```
TextUtils.concat(*yourListOfText.map { it.cloneWithSpans() }.toTypedArray())
```

Now you can concatenate tons of `CharSequences` without worrying about losing any of the styles and formatting you have on them!

Note that this will work for *most* styles, it doesn't work all the time but should be enough to cover all the basic styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to ask a question: What does that `*` do in this situation ?

Comment: @MBH It's the [spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389003/kotlin-asterisk-operator-before-variable-name-or-spread-operator-in-kotlin)