# Error in merging spannable objects

Tags: android

I want to merge 3 spannable objects. This code works fine:

```
Spannable s1 = new SpannableStringBuilder("bold");
             s1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, s1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
             Spannable s2 = new SpannableStringBuilder("not");
             Spannable s3 = new SpannableStringBuilder("BOLD");
             s3.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, s3.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
             finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(s1,s2);
             finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(finishSpan,s3);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

or `finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(s1,s2,s3);`

I have the same code but when I merge 3 object,the result is wrong.
I have checked that the type of certain elements are true.
beginningOfModifiedSpannable is bold, selectionSpannable is normal,endOfModifiedSpannable is bold
But their merging is wrong. Only the last part of the result string is bold. Why it happens?? I have the same code above and it works well!

```
  Spannable str = contentText.getText();
            Spannable selectionSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            StyleSpan[] ss = selectionSpannable.getSpans(0, selectionSpannable.length(), StyleSpan.class);

            boolean exists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
                if (ss[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD){
                 selectionSpannable.removeSpan(ss[i]);
                    exists = true;
                }
            }

            if (!exists){
                str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else {

             Spannable endOfModifiedSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, selectionEnd, contentText.getText().length());
             Spannable beginningOfModifiedSpannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(str, 0, selectionStart);
             Spanned finishSpan = null;

             if(beginningOfModifiedSpannable.length() > 0) {

              if(endOfModifiedSpannable.length() > 0) {
               finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(beginningOfModifiedSpannable,selectionSpannable);
               finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(finishSpan,endOfModifiedSpannable);
                 }
              else {
               finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(beginningOfModifiedSpannable,selectionSpannable);
              }

             }
             else {
              if(endOfModifiedSpannable.length() > 0) {
               finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(selectionSpannable,endOfModifiedSpannable);
                     }
                  else {
                   finishSpan = selectionSpannable;
                  }
                 }
contentText.setText(finishSpan);
```

**I repeat that I have checked that 3 parts are true**. E.g. I have 3 parts:
**Hel** lo,wor  **ld**

I have noticed that the first merging is right:

```
finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(beginningOfModifiedSpannable,selectionSpannable);
```

It looks like **Hel**lo,wor

But the second is wrong

```
finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(finishSpan,endOfModifiedSpannable);
```

or this merging is wrong:

```
finishSpan = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(finishSpan,selectionSpannable,endOfModifiedSpannable);
```

And the result of wrong string is:
Hello,wo**rld**

But the true result must be like this:

**Hel**lo,**world**

Nonsense!

Answer (score 16):

the problem is that you most probably use the same CharacterStyle instance for both parts, the 1st and 3rd. You need to use a new instance every time you add a style to a Spannable object.

e.g.

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello,world");
    CharacterStyle c = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    ssb.setSpan(c, 0, 3, 0);
    ssb.setSpan(c, 9, 11, 0);
```

this will result into Hello,Wor**ld**

to get a correct result you must do something like this:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello,world");
    CharacterStyle c = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    CharacterStyle c2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    ssb.setSpan(c, 0, 3, 0);
    ssb.setSpan(c2, 9, 11, 0);
```

Comment: CharacterStyle c2 = CharacterStyle.wrap(c) does also the job.

Comment: great solution. I also noticed the problem appearing when different StringBuilder objects try applying the same Style instance.

Answer (score 0):

Extending what @tagtraeumer has recommended here's another scenario where some additional fiddling is required.

Apparently applying the same style instance to different SpannableStringBuilder objects also does not work.

**for eg.** The below snippet of code will apply ***mystyle*** only to ***txt1*** in the text box. For whatever reason ***mystyle*** gets ripped out of ***txt2***

```
TextView tv;
StyleSpan mystyle = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

SpannableStringBuilder txt1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(somestring);
txt1.setSpan(mystyle,0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableStringBuilder txt2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(anotherstring);
txt2.setSpan(mystyle,0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(TextUtils.concat(txt1, txt2));
```

To be able to see your styles appearing for all Spannable objects create unique style objects and apply these to each Spannable String Builder object

```
TextView tv;
StyleSpan mystyle1 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
StyleSpan mystyle2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

SpannableStringBuilder txt1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(somestring);
txt1.setSpan(mystyle1,0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableStringBuilder txt2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(anotherstring);
txt2.setSpan(mystyle2,0,5,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(TextUtils.concat(txt1, txt2));
```