# Kotlin asterisk operator before variable name or Spread Operator in Kotlin

Tags: syntax, kotlin

I want to know what exactly an asterisk does before a variable name in Kotlin.
I saw this (`*args`) in a [Spring boot Kotlin example](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin):

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class Application {

    @Bean
    open fun init(repository: CustomerRepository) = CommandLineRunner {
        repository.save(Customer("Jack", "Bauer"))
        repository.save(Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"))
        repository.save(Customer("Kim", "Bauer"))
        repository.save(Customer("David", "Palmer"))
        repository.save(Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"))
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The `*` operator is known as the **Spread Operator** in Kotlin.

From the [Kotlin Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> When you call a `vararg`-function, you can pass arguments  individually, for example `asList(1, 2, 3)`. if you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with `*`):

It can be applied to an Array before passing it into a function that accepts `vararg`.

#### For Example...

If you have a function that accepts a varied number of arguments...

```
fun sumOfNumbers(vararg numbers: Int): Int {
    return numbers.sum()
}
```

Use the spread operator to pass an array's elements as the arguments:

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(2, 3, 4)
val sum = sumOfNumbers(*numbers)
println(sum) // Prints '9'
```

---

**Notes:**

- The `*` operator is also the **multiplication operator** (of course).
- The operator can only be used when passing arguments to a function. The result of the operation **cannot be stored** since it yields no value (it is *purely* syntactic sugar).
- The operator may confuse some C/C++ programmers at first because it looks like a pointer is being de-referenced. It isn't; Kotlin has **no notion of pointers**.
- The operator can be used **in-between other arguments** when calling a `vararg`-function. This is demonstrated in the example [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs).
- The operator is similar to the `apply` function in various functional programming languages.

Comment: Is Spread operator inline array? For example for array a = [1, 2, 3] funWithVararg(*a) inlines into funWithVararg(1,2,3)? I mean in bytecode level.

Comment: You may want to add to your list of notes, that it works exactly the same as in Python.

Comment: `The operator can only be used when passing arguments to a function. ` helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the answers that were directly towards "what is this thing!?!", you often have the case where you have a `List` and want to pass it to a function that is expecting a `vararg`.  For this, the conversion is:

```
someFunc(x, y, *myList.toTypedArray())
```

Assuming that last parameter of `someFunc` is `vararg` of the same type as the elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! This should be in the official docs under the spread operator section as something to watch out for when your spread operator is not working.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpfull. Wondering what is "Spread Operator" behind the scenes? Is just a way to get a varargs value?

Comment: Actually, you're not passing a List, it only works for arrays; that's why -in your example- you have to convert it.

Answer (score 13):

As described in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) this is a spread operator:

> When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g.
>   asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its
>   contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array
>   with *):
>
> ```
> val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3) 
> val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
> ```

Answer (score 8):

If a function which accept a vararg(Variable number of arguments) parameter like:

```
fun sum(vararg data:Int)
{
   // function body here         
}
```

Now to call this method, we can do:

```
sum(1,2,3,4,5)
```

But what if we have these value in an array, like:

```
val array= intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
```

then, to call this method we have to use spread operator, like:

```
 sum(*array)
```

Here, *(spread operator) will pass all content of that array.

> ***array** is equivalent to **1,2,3,4,5**

But wait a minute, what if we call it like this: `sum(array)`
it will give us Type Mismatch compile time error:

> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:Int
> Found:IntArray
> ```

The problem is `sum` function accept a `vararg Int` parameter(which accept value like: 1,2,3,4,5) and if we pass array, it will be passed as `IntArray`.

Answer (score 7):

In Java you can pass an array as is but an advantage of unpacking an array with spread operator `*` is that spread operator lets you combine the values from an array and some fixed values in a single call. Java doesn't support this.

Comment: Upvoted, because I asked myself why they implemented it like this. I'm still not 100% sure about it. I mean, couldn't they just infer this in most cases?

Comment: @TimBüthe In some cases, it wouldn't be possible to infer it, consider the following cases `val resultOne = arrayOf(intArrayOne, intArrayTwo)` and `val resultTwo = arrayOf(*intArrayOne, *intArrayTwo)`. Type of `resultOne` and `resultTwo` are respectively `Array<Int>` and `Array<Array<Int>>`. I beleive that's one of the reasons