# How does one pass an Array<Int> to a vararg Int function using the Spread Operator?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, groovy-spread

I have a vararg function that takes multiple `Int`s. I have an `Array<Int>` that I'd like to use as input.

### An unsuccessful attempt:

Here is my attempt to call the function using the [Spread Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389045/5601284):

```
fun printNumbers(vararg numbers: Int) {
    numbers.forEach { it -> println(it) }
}

val numbers: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
printNumbers(*numbers)
```

However, I'm getting the following type mismatch error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Int> but IntArray was expected
printNumbers(*arrayOf<Int>(1, 2, 3))
              ^
```

### Extra confusion:

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, especially since I can use the spread operator on an `Array<String>`. For example...

```
fun printStrings(vararg strings: String) {
    strings.forEach { it -> println(it) }
}

val strings: Array<String> = arrayOf("hello", "there", "stackoverflow")
printStrings(*strings)
```

Output:

```
hello
there
stackoverflow
```

### Attempts to correct the error:

- I searched online to see if it was possible to convert an `Array<Int>` to an `IntArray`, as this might satisfy the compiler. I couldn't see anything except the [opposite conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) (`IntArray` to `Array<Int>`)
- I tried specifying the generic type when calling `arrayOf`. E.g. `arrayOf<Int>(1, 2, 3)`. This (for obvious reasons) didn't work.

### Notes:

- I'm using Kotlin version 1.0.3
- I think some of my confusion stems from the fact that I don't understand the difference between `Array<Int>` and `IntArray` and when to choose one over the other.

---

How do I pass an `Array<Int>` into a vararg function that expects multiple `Int`s?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically, `Array<Int>` is an array of boxed `Integer` objects under the hood, while `IntArray` translates to an array of primitive `int` values (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094889/4465208)).

To pass in an `Array<Int>` to a vararg function, you can use the `toIntArray()` function to convert it to an `IntArray` first:

```
val numbers: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
printNumbers(*numbers.toIntArray())
```

Or if you can, create the array as an `IntArray` to begin with - this way you avoid the allocation of an extra array in the process, as well as the boxing of each individual value:

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
printNumbers(*numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the boxed `Integer`s when creating an `Array<Int>`. This does not work well with `vararg Int`. It works with an [`IntArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/-init-.html) though:

```
val numbers: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
printNumbers(*numbers.toIntArray())
```

Or directly create the array with the correct type:

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
printNumbers(*numbers)
```

Using an `IntArray`, as opposed to `Array<Int>`, removes the boxing overhead, which surely is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was tough for me to pick one to mark as the accepted answer. I appreciate your efforts.