# How to pass attribute values of a certain type without using constructor in kotlin (like spread operator in ES6/TS)?

Tags: kotlin

I use the **object spread** operator in ES6/typescript a lot to pass attribute values. For example, in typescript:

```
interface Control { id?: String, width?: number, height?: number }

function buildTextBoxControl(dataFromDb: any, options: Control) : TextBoxControl {
    return { ...options, text: dataFromDb.name }
}
```

Then I can call the method like:

```
buildTextBoxControl(objFromDb, { height: 45 })
buildTextBoxControl(objFromDb, { width: 25, id: "some-id" })
```

How can I acheive the equivalent in kotlin? Or in short, how can the method `buildTextBoxControl` be written in kotlin?

The key thing here is that the spread operator automatically sets the attribute values from the other object without having to manually set them one-by-one using the kotlin's `apply { }`

Comment: Is this kotlinjs you're talking about?

Comment: @MuliYulzary Not really. Just kotlin. I mentioned about ES6/TS just because there is a spread object operator there which I couldn't find an equivalent for in kotlin.

Comment: There's a spread operator in Kotlin but it's only for arrays and only for vararg params. AFAIK There's nothing equivalent in Kotlin.

Comment: Can you write what should be returned in your two sample cases? `return { ...options, text: dataFromDb.name }` should become `return { height: 45, text: dataFromDb.name }` and `return { width: 25, id: "some-id", text: dataFromDb.name }` analogically?

Comment: @michalbrz Yes, it should return those. The spread operator enables me to avoid having to know before-hand and list out all the attributes manually.

Answer (score -4):

You can't do that.

The Kotlin spread operatør ([`*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389045/6296561)) is limited to vararg spreading of an Array. From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> When we call a `vararg`-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. `asList(1, 2, 3)`, or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with `*`):

That limits your use of the spread operator.

Additionally, bracket-based initialization does not work, because it creates a function instead:

```kotlin
interface Control { 
    var id: String?
    var width: Number?
    var height: Number?
}

class TextBoxControl {
    var id: String? = null
    var width: Number? = null
    var height: Number? = null
    var text: String? = null
    

}

fun createControl() : TextBoxControl {
    return {};
}
```

> Error:(17, 11) Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but TextBoxControl was expected

TL;DR:

You cannot initialize it by using `{}`. You cannot use the spread operator to get arguments.

---

There are a few ways you can solve it without using constructors, but none of them are flexible (without digging into reflection, but that's a performance drop).

First of all though, I **highly** suggest you prefer constructors. It's much easier to deal with in Kotlin:

```kotlin
interface Control { 
    var id: String?
    var width: Number?
    var height: Number?
}
// Created just to have something to pass as options
class ControlImpl() : Control {
    override var id: String? = "Hello World!"
    override var width: Number? = 314159
    override var height: Number? = 271
}

data class TextBoxControl(var id: String? = null,
    var width: Number? = null,
    var height: Number? = null,
    var text: String? = null)

fun buildTextBoxControl(dataFromDb: String, options: Control) : TextBoxControl {
    return TextBoxControl(id = options.id, width = options.width, height = options.width, text = dataFromDb /*Not entirely what you had, but this is just for the sake of my answer*/)
}
fun main() {
    var control = buildTextBoxControl("String", ControlImpl().apply { 
        id = "id"
        width = 42
        height = 42 
    })
    println(control)
}
```

> TextBoxControl(id=id, width=42, height=42, text=String)

This is considerably easier than the alternative approaches, and likely more memory-efficient as well, because Kotlin doesn't have native support for the syntax you want.

Kotlin (and Java in general for that matter) is simply designed in a way that requires constructors. JS/TS relies heavier on map-style classes, and I believe initializing them is just an extension of map init syntax. Kotlin classes aren't maps.

---

**Note:** If you have absolutely no idea what variables you might get from the control object, and still need to use all, I **highly recommend** you re-design your code. Neither Kotlin or Java is designed for "I'll give you some stuff at runtime and you have to figure it out". The closest thing you get to that is reflection, but it's still limited by the fields you have at hand.

If, however, you *want* to have no idea what fields you have and don't have, use a Map instead of a class. This does come with all the negative side-effects of not having a class, such as no compile-time field verification, but that's the price you're paying here. Not every convenient shortcut in one language translates into another.

Otherwise, and if you really don't want to use constructors even though they're *the* way to design stuff using Kotlin, you have two options:

## Manually setting the fields

If the problem is conversion, you can throw in a function to convert it:

```kotlin
fun Control.toTextBoxControl() : TextBoxControl{
    return TextBoxControl().let { it ->
        it.id = this.id
        it.width = this.width
        it.height = this.height
        it
    }
}
```

Now you can convert a Control to an overridden type relatively easily:

```kotlin
fun buildTextBoxControl(dataFromDb: String, options: Control) : TextBoxControl {
    return options.toTextBoxControl()
}
```

But what about additional arguments? They've been ignored so far.

If you **really** want to go constructorless, you can use `operator fun invoke` to change parameters:

```
class TextBoxControl {
    var id: String? = null
    var width: Number? = null
    var height: Number? = null
    var text: String? = null
    
    operator fun invoke(id: String? = null, width: Number? = null, height: Number? = null, text: String? = null)
            : TextBoxControl{
        if (id != null) this.id = id;
        if (width != null) this.width = width;
        if (height != null) this.height = height;
        if (text != null) this.text = text;
        return this
    }
    override fun toString() : String {
        return "TextBoxControl(id=$id, width: $width=height=$height, text=$text)"
    }
}
```

Not particularly pretty. I also hit a design issue with this - I can't really find a decent way to allow null using invoke. If there is no null check, all the original variables will be overridden.

Anyway, this lets you change the conversion function and the creation function:

```kotlin
fun Control.toTextBoxControl() : TextBoxControl{
    return TextBoxControl()(id = id, width = width, height = height)
}
fun buildTextBoxControl(dataFromDb: String, options: Control) : TextBoxControl {
    return options.toTextBoxControl()(text = dataFromDb)
}
```

If you're not familiar with what `operator fun invoke` means, it's syntactic sugar for invoking an object. So if you have an instance of an object that has an `operator fun invoke()`, you can write `someInstanceOfTheClass()`. It can have arguments and a return type as you see fit. You can read more about operator overloading in Kotlin [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

## Reflection

**WARNING:** Reflection comes with a heavy toll on performance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392351/6296561) for details.

Throwing in a map to the Control interface (which returns the values as a map - also memory-inefficient and another reason to use constructors), you can iterate over the map and use reflection to set values:

```
interface Control { 
    var id: String?
    var width: Number?
    var height: Number?
    
    fun toMap() = mutableMapOf("id" to id, "width" to width, "height" to height) as MutableMap<String, Any>
}
class ControlImpl() : Control {
    override var id: String? = "Hello World!"
    override var width: Number? = 314159
    override var height: Number? = 271
}

class TextBoxControl {
    var id: String? = null
    var width: Number? = null
    var height: Number? = null
    var text: String? = null
    
    // this could also be a static function called `createTextBoxControlFromMap`, non-static function, or thrown into an apply block or generic extension function
    operator fun invoke(map: Map<String, Any>) : TextBoxControl {
        for((k, v) in map) {
            val f = this::class.java.getDeclaredField(k)
            f.setAccessible(true)
            f.set(this, v)
        }
        return this;
    }
}

fun buildTextBoxControl(dataFromDb: String, options: Control) : TextBoxControl {
    return TextBoxControl()(options.toMap().apply { 
        put("text", dataFromDb) 
    })
}

fun main() {
    var control = buildTextBoxControl("String", ControlImpl().apply { 
        id = "id"
        width = 42
        height = 42 
    })
    println(control)
}
```

But again, **please consider using constructors**. Except when there are no other ways but to use reflection, you shouldn't consider reflection. There are better design options than diving into reflection, even though they aren't as short as TS syntax.