# How to Convert Array to Set (HashSet) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, hashmap

I have an array of String

```
val array = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

I need to convert it to HashSet

```
val set = HashSet<String>()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use extension function `toHashSet` as follow

```
array.toHashSet()
```

That function belongs to Kotlin Library

```
/**
 * Returns a [HashSet] of all elements.
 */
public fun <T> Array<out T>.toHashSet(): HashSet<T> {
    return toCollection(HashSet<T>(mapCapacity(size)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Array to Set**

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val array = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
    val set = HashSet(Arrays.asList(*array))

    println("Set: $set")

}
```

When you run the program, the output will be:

```
Set: [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Could you explain the * in `val set = HashSet(Arrays.asList(*array))`. Please ?

Comment: @Hussien Fahmy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389003/kotlin-asterisk-operator-before-variable-name-or-spread-operator-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Collections Solution

Directly use `toSet(*array)` or `toHashSet(*array)`. These are part of Kotlin's standard library.

The asterisk `*` is the `spread` operator. It applies all elements in a collection individually, each passed in order to a `vararg` method parameter.

```
val array = arrayOf("data", "foo")

// Multiple spreads ["data", "foo", "bar", "data", "foo"]
val mySet = setOf(*array, "bar", *array)
```

Passing no parameters `setOf()` results in an empty set.

These are all of the specific hash types you can use:

```
setOf()
hashSetOf()
linkedSetOf()
mutableSetOf()
sortableSetOf()
```

This is how to define the collection item type explicitly.

```
setOf<String>()
hashSetOf<MyClass>()
```