# Android and Kotlin varargs: formatted strings returns garbage

Tags: android, kotlin, resources, variadic-functions, android-resources

I'm encountering a strange problem: I've a general function which is used to retrieve resource strings (it's just to avoid writing context.resources.getString() everytime):

```
protected fun string(@StringRes stringRes: Int, vararg args: String): String = app.getString(stringRes, args)
```

worked fine up until now, when I added the varargs to retrieve formatted strings. Simple strings still work fine but when I tried to retrieve a formatted one:

```
string(R.string.formatted_string, myId)
```

my string resource:

```
<string name="formatted_string">#%s</string>
```

I get some garbage:

```
#[Ljava.lang.String;@3a59711
```

expected:

```
#4848684
```

the garbage change with the resource I request

It looks a Object identifier.

If I don't use the method it works fine

What is happening here?

Comment: What you're seeing is the return value of `String[].toString()`. The function observes its `vararg` arguments as a single argument, which is an array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution for you is to use the **spread operator** `*`:

```
fun string(@StringRes stringRes: Int, vararg args: String): String = getString(stringRes, *args)
```

[Variable number of arguments (Varargs)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Comment: Indeed. See this answer for reference on official documentation regarding this asterisk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389003/kotlin-asterisk-operator-before-variable-name-or-spread-operator-in-kotlin

Comment: thanks, I didn't understood the asterisk was needed in this case.