# What does a prefixed asterisk mean

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following Kotlin code:

```
single(name = walletOkHttpTag) {
        createOkHttpClient {
            addHeaders(
                *mutableListOf<Pair<String, String>>().apply {
                    add(HeaderKey.ACCEPT to APPLICATION_JSON_HEADER)
                    if (isDebug || isBeta) {
                        add(HeaderKey.AUTHORIZATION to BASIC_AUTH_WALLET_STAGE_HEADER)
                    }
                }.toTypedArray()
            )
        }
    }
```

What does the asterisk * mean that is in front of mutableListOf?

Comment: nice question from person with 53 score Kotlin tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin asterisk operator before variable name or Spread Operator in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389003/kotlin-asterisk-operator-before-variable-name-or-spread-operator-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the **spread** operator and it is required to pass an existing array to a `vararg` function.

> When we call a `vararg`-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. `asList(1, 2, 3)`, or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the **spread** operator (prefix the array with `*`):

Simplified example from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val list = listOf(-1, 0, *a, 4)
println(list)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Without the spread operator, the array itself would be added as a single element, resulting in a `List<Serializable>` with 4 elements:

```
[-1, 0, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@31befd9f, 4]
```