# How should i interpet this syntax in kotlin? The syntax is weird and not easy to figure out

Tags: kotlin

I have working with kotlin for more than one year and written a lot of code so far.
However today i saw following code, and honestly i do not understand the syntax. A lot of research resulted in 0 output.
The code i am looks like this

```
var list1 = arrayOfNulls<Int>(7)
var list2 = arrayOfNulls<Int>(8)
arrayListOf(*list2) + arrayListOf(*list1)
```

The syntax is new for me and i have not seen it before. Can someone explain it for me. What i do not understans ius the star part (*) in the arrayListOf(*list2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389003/kotlin-asterisk-operator-before-variable-name-or-spread-operator-in-kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explination from the official Kotlin Doc:

> When you call a vararg -function, you can pass arguments individually, for example asList(1, 2, 3). If you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with *):

```kotlin
val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
```

[Kotlin Docs - varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)